# What is the definition of Sati Nari in kaliyug?

Tags: women, kali-yuga, sita, identification-request

In the Ramayana, we call Sita a Sati Nari, I listen it from my childhood days.

As I don't know what Sita was doing or having so that she call as Sati.

But  In Kaliyuga we are here up to what we understand as a Sati, how can I assume my self as a Sati Nari as I don't know it's real definitions and it's properties, also don't know what are the lakhyans of a Sati Nari.

My question is "what are the real definitions or lakhyans of a Sati Nari in this society of Kaliyuga", comparing to which I can my self assume whether I am Sati or not. If not then I will try to follow it to be a Sati Nari.

**Edited**

I am a man, I am asking this question assuming that I am a woman because I was being asked this question by a woman.

Comment: "**Sati**" is the female form of the word "**Sat(सत्)**". Sat(सत्) means truth or real or pure. MahaShakti is called सती Sati, as She is the ultimate reality and essence of truth. सती Sati does not mean a woman who burnt herself. For a true woman, who is righteous, Sati is designated. Yes Sati did become a Pratha. But Sati in all means Truth and Real and Pure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A woman is considers as Sati if her husband meant everything for her. Who worship her husband as Lord. Who thinks her whole life is for my husband's service(sewa), those women are considered as Sati Because as per hinduism, women's greatest dharma is towards her husband more than anyone/anything else.

Following [Ramayana verse](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/ayodhya/sarga117/ayodhya_117_frame.htm) explains the women's dharma towards their husband which told by great female ascetic(also wife of great Sage Atri) Anansuya to Sita.

> **duhshiilaH kaama vR^itto vaa dhanair vaa parivarjitaH |
>
> striiNaam aarya svabhaavaanaam paramam daivatam patiH || 2-117-23**
>
> striiNaam= to women; aaryasvabhaavaanaam= of noble nature; patiH= husband; paramam= is the hightest daivatam= deity; duSiilaH= whether he is ill-behaved; kaama vR^ittovaa= or licentious; parivarjitovaa= or devoid of; dhanaiH= riches.
>
> *"To women of noble nature, the husband is the highest deity no mater whether he is ill-behaved or licentious or devoid of riches."*
>
> **na ato vishiShTam pashyaami baandhavam vimR^ishanty aham |
>
> sarvatra yogyam vaidehi tapaH kR^itam iva avyayam || 2-117-24**
>
> vaidehi= O, Seetha!; vimR^ishantii= On a reflection; na pashyaami= I perceive; na= none; vishiSTam= who is a better; baandhavam= friend; ataH= than a husband; yogyam= who protects his wife; sarvatra= in all circumstances; avyayam iva= like the imperishable fruit; kR^itam= accomplished; tapaH= of one's austerities.
>
> *"O, Seetha! On a reflection, I perceive none who is a better friend than a husband, who protects his wife in all circumstances, like the imperishable fruit of one's austerities."*
>
> **na tu evam avagagcCanti guNa doSham asat striyaH |
>
> kaama vaktavya hR^idayaa bhartR^i naathaaH caranti yaaH || 2-117-25**
>
> yaaH= those women; kaama vaktavya hR^idayaaH= whose hearts follow their passions; charanti= and, conduct themselves; bhartR^inaathaaH= dominating their husbands; aststriyaH= such evil women; na avagachchhanti= having no understanding; guNa doSam= of virtue and vice; evam= (do not follow him) in the aforesaid manner.
>
> *"Those evil women, whose hearts follow their passions and conduct themselves dominating their husband, having no understanding of virtue and vice, do not follow him in the aforesaid manner."*
>
> **praapnuvanty ayashaH caiva dharma bhramsham ca maithili |
>
> akaarya vasham aapannaaH striyo yaaH khalu tad vidhaaH || 2-117-26**
>
> maithili= O, Seetha!; khalu= Indeed; yaaH striyaH= those women; aapannaH= who get into akaarya vasham= an improper act of authority; tadvidhaaH= in the aforesaid manner; praapnuvanti= reap; ayashashcha= infamy; dharma bhramsham= and decline of righteousness.
>
> *"O, Seetha! Surely, those evil women, who get into an improper act of authority over their husbands reap infamy and decline in righteousness."*
>
> **tvad vidhaaH tu guNair yuktaa dR^iShTa loka para avaraaH |
>
> striyaH svarge cariShyanti yathaa puNya kR^itaH tathaa || 2-117-27**
>
> striyastu= women; tvadvidhaaH= like you; yuktaaH= who are endowed; guNaiH= with virtues; dR^iSTa loka paraaparaaH= who look with detachment on prosperity and adversity in this world; yathaa tathaa= therefore; chariSyanti= dwell; svarge= in heaven; yathaa= as; dharmakR^itaH= those who performed meritorious deeds.
>
> *"Women, like you, on the other hand who are endowed with virtues, who look with detachment on prosperity and adversity in this world, therefore dwell in heaven as those who performed meritorious deeds."*
>
> **evam vidhaaH ca pravaraaH striyo bhartR^i dR^iDha vrataaH |
>
> deva loke mahiiyante puNyena svena karmaNaa || 2-118-12**
>
> evam vidhaaH= such; pravaraaH= excellent; striyaH= women; bhartR^idriDha vrataaH= devoted to their husbands; svena= by their own; puNyena= meritorious; karmaNaa= deed; mahiiyante= are highly honoured; devaloke= in heaven.
>
> *"Such excellent women, devoted to their husbands, and by their meritorious deeds, are highly honoured in heaven."*